# how to build comments in a blog for a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

i  am building a blog and would like to know good tools and plugins to implement a commenting system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One good place to go looking for things you need (for ruby and rails) is the [ruby toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com).

For instance: for commenting you can find all the gems [here](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_comments.html).
I would recommend the [act_as_commentable](http://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable) gem.

On the other hand, handling comments is in most cases so easy in rails, it is also very easy to do it yourself, and there are a lot of tutorials out there that explain that in great detail. For example [here](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Tutorials/Ruby-In-Steel-Tutorials/Rails,25/How-To-Create-A-Ruby-On-Rails-Blog,168).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

goto http://www.disqus.com and signup, then try something like [norman's disqus plugin](http://github.com/norman/disqus)

OR:

use http://aboutecho.com/ - it's really nice

Comment: it seems hard to install and configure is there something more basic?

Comment: @fenec Really? `gem install disqus` then `Disqus::defaults[:api_key] = "my_disqus_api_key"` in config/production.rb then `disqus_thread` on your post page to load the thread, and `disqus_combo(:color => "blue", :hide_mods => false, :num_items => 20)` to show the combo box is hard? How could it get more basic?

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for a CMS system, I've read about Refinery CMS, it already supports Rails 3, http://refinerycms.com/

Answer (score 0):

The absolutely best resource I have found so far (I am learning Ruby on Rails for the first time) is the online book [railstutorial](http://railstutorial.org), by Michael Hartl. It is a tutorial that goes through, step by step, the creation of a simple but functional social network. Good luck!